# keycloak adapter failed to enforce policy decision NoHttpResponseException

Tags: oauth, keycloak, jsessionid

We are using keycloak as auth server. We have jetty as app server which has keycloak configured as auth resource server (using keycloak adapter).
We have java client desktop applications which connect to jetty for REST calls. Whenever client app starts, it asks for login (using KeycloakInstalled Java plugin). It gets the token and passes it in every subsequent requests to Jetty. This whole flow works smoothly with no issue.

Now, when I check Jetty http logs, I see one call to KC server for every incoming call to Jetty. This call is `/auth/realms/{realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token`
As I increase the load on Jetty server, above KC call starts failing with below error:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: <jetty_url> failed to respond
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to enforce policy decisions.
```

Due to this every call becomes unresponsive and system goes down.

Now I have few questions:
1) Why KC adapter is firing above call to KC on every request? Is there setting that KC adapter can cache 
the result for some time.
2) I believe above exception is some issue in httpclient which KC adapter uses internally. Is there something that we can change here?
3) Whenever I fire rest call from browser (which internally redirects to KC and asks for login), the above KC /token call never happens. The difference between desktop client vs browser request is that browser sets cookie which has JSESSIONID and session_state. Should our desktop client also use JSESSIONID instead of token? what is the correct way? If yes, how to get the JSESSIONID. I could get the session_state from token.

Please help.